# c# check if contentplaceholder has a userdefined control

Tags: c#, contentplaceholder

I have a situation where in I am adding .js file to my aspx page using content place holder.
I need to add all the js to end of the page(the said content place holder is at bottom of the master page)

Here's the code for the same

```
 ContentPlaceHolder content = (ContentPlaceHolder)Page.Master.FindControl("additionalJavaScript");
                content.Controls.Add(new DeferedMinifiedScript("~/Scripts/Controls/ListBoxControl.js"));
```

Now the issue is I need to add the ListBoxControl.js file only once on the page. 
But this is adding the file everytime a new listbox control is rendered on the page.

I need to put a check in place to see if the file is already available as control on page then skip adding it again.

I tried the following

```
var abc = new DeferedMinifiedScript("~/Scripts/Controls/ListBoxControl.js");
if(content.Controls.Contains(abc))
{
//Don't add the file again.
}
```

But this is still adding the file again and again.

Is there a way out?

Also, I can't use RegisterClientScriptInclude or similar functions

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx

and Set the contents to a string and then use string to compare to see if it contains your .js string/path to file, then if it does do not do.

Comment: Can't do this also.